# Finding K smallest values in an array (Heap vs QuickSelect)

Tags: arrays, data-structures, quicksort

Let's assume that we have an array and we wish to find K smallest values of it :

There are two approaches :

1.Using quick select algorithm (O(n) time complexity and O(1) space)

2.Using min heap data structure (O(NlogK) time complexity and O(K) space)

I'd like to know when one is preferred over another one.

I guess both of them can be distributed.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something, but the O(n) time, O(1) space is for *one* run of median-of-medians, while the heap complexity is given for getting k elements. Compare apples to appels, either 1. is O(kn) time, O(k) space or the bounds on 2. have to be fixed (not sure right now what the right ones would be).

Comment: If we don't want to distribute the array, it's apparently can be done in O(n) time , but if we want to distribute it , the space complexity would be O(k) but the time would remain O(n) , because we visit some elements for only 1 time (those which are out of the range) and some for fixed number of times (which depends on how we split the large array)

Answer (score 2):

Check this [out](http://blog.teamleadnet.com/2012/07/quick-select-algorithm-find-kth-element.html):-

> **Quick select than sorting or heap**
>
> As sorting the whole dataset is quite slow, it makes sense to select
>   the top K items and sort only that few ‘top’ elements giving the
>   impression to the user as the whole dataset was sorted as she pages
>   through the result set. This will give a running time of O(k*log(k) +
>   n) as opposed to O(n*log(n)) which is much faster if K is reasonably
>   small (few hundreds for example).
>
> An other approach would be to work with a heap and keep popping the
>   smallest number while putting back a larger as we are receiving the N
>   numbers as a stream. This would work with O(n*log(K)) running time as
>   the heap holds K elements so the height is log(K) while we test N
>   numbers in total, although it’s expected running time is larger than
>   the quick select and sort combination.

Comment: I don't get it , why `O(klogk + n)` ? isn't the quickselect running time `O(n)` ?

Comment: Yes it is n + 1/2 n + 1/4 n + 1/8 n + ..... < 2 n i.e, O(n). Did you read the link which I mentioned?

Comment: Yes, but we don't want the k smallest/largest to be sorted in the result (I guess it assumes so which result additional `O(klogk)`).