# QuickSelect vs MaxHeap for k'th largest element

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, heap, quicksort

> Problem statement: Given an array and a number k where k is smaller
> than the size of the array, we need to find the k’th smallest element
> in the given array. It is given that all array elements are distinct.

Out of 5 methods [here](https://www.cdn.geeksforgeeks.org/kth-smallestlargest-element-unsorted-array/), I want to ask a doubt regarding two methods, namely `MaxHeap`(method 3) and `QuickSelect`(method 4).

> My question : Which one should I prefer?

I understand that time complexity for method 3 is `O(k + (n-k)*Logk)` but method 4 has worst time complexity `O(n^2)` and average time complexity `O(n)`. Although, quickSelect method seems more preferable but then it has quadratic worst time complexity.

I have gone through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258209/finding-k-smallest-values-in-an-array-heap-vs-quickselect) as well but I am not satisfied with the answer.

Comment: Random shuffle the array may help to avoid O(n^2)

Comment: @starboy_jb QuickSelect method is already using random pivots.

Comment: This seems easy to benchmark yourself. Have you done so? In the end it only matters how it turns out for your case, your programming language, your data, your requirements for worst case scenarios. If you find it unacceptable to have a theoretical probability to get a O(n²) performance in rare cases, then your choice is made. If that is acceptable knowing that in the vast majority of cases you'll be near linear, then your choice is also made.

Comment: @trincot Right. I am convinced.